# How to fix Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined - How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am making a electron app but the error said `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

This is my code:

```
const remote = require('electron').remote

var minimise = document.getElementById('minimise');
var maximise = document.getElementById('maximise');
var quit = document.getElementById('quit');

minimise.addEventListener('click', minimiseApp);
maximise.addEventListener('click', maximiseApp);
quit.addEventListener('click', quitApp);

function minimiseApp() {
    remote.BrowserView.getFocusedWindow().minimize();
}

function maximiseApp() {
    remote.BrowserView.getFocusedWindow().maximize();
}

function quitApp() {
    remote.BrowserView.getFocusedWindow().close();
}
```

How to fix it?
Please give me solutions
But they should at least work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please specify node integration as true when the browser window (where this HTML file is embedded) was originally created in the main process.

```
function createAddItemWindow() {
//Create new window
addItemWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    title: 'Add Item',

    //The lines below solved the issue
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
})}
```

Comment: @ErrorLane, this is solution for Electron users. Does it work for you?